# Passing the contents of a text file as JSON to httpBody

Tags: swift

FIGURED IT OUT, See below:

I'm trying to create a program that can pass the contents of a text file to a http POST request in swift. I am storing filters for API queries that I am running in the text files, and would like to pass them as JSON objects(? I think, anyway) to request.httpBody in the request. I'm having problems converting the txt files to something that the httpBody can accept as data (json object?).

Here an example txt file. Filters in the same array are combined using OR logic. Arrays of filters are combined using AND logic, so I have to account for both cases.:

zero_RC.txt

```
{
    "query": "Zero Response Code",
    "filters": [
    {
        "filters": [
        {
            "field": "inventoryState",
            "value": "CONFIRMED",
            "type": "IN"
        },
        {
            "field": "responseCode",
            "value": "0",
            "type": "EQ"
        },
        {
            "field": "exception",
            "value": "DNS lookup failed",
            "type": "EQ"
        }]
    }]
}
```

This is the block that I'm trying to get to work. I believe that I need a JSON object, and can pass that to httpBody in the request below. But, still a beginner at this stuff.

```
    // get JSON, somehow
    let file = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "zero_RC", ofType: "txt")
    let jsonData = file!.data(using: .utf8)

    let JSON = try! JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: jsonData as Any, options: [])

    if JSONSerialization.isValidJSONObject(JSON) {
        print("Oh Yeah")
    } else {
        print("Nah bud, that ain't working")
    }


    // make the request
    var request = URLRequest(url: url)
    request.httpMethod = "POST"
    request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")
    request.addValue("Basic \(loginData!)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
    request.httpBody = JSON
```

So am I taking a string and converting to data, then into a JSON object? I'm thoroughly confused as to how best to do this. I've searched and searched and all I'm finding is parsing articles, which don't exactly help.

Thanks ahead of time.

---

ANSWERED:

The problem was in the request.setValue. I needed to use `Content-Type` instead of `Accept`.

```
    // get JSON
    let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "zero_RC", ofType: "txt")
    let data = try! Data(contentsOf: URL(fileURLWithPath: path!), options: .mappedIfSafe)


    // make the request
    var request = URLRequest(url: url)
    request.httpMethod = "POST"
    request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    request.addValue("Basic \(loginData!)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
    request.httpBody = data
```

Comment: The data in your text file has already been serialized to JSON, so there is no need to serialize it again. Just assign `jsonData` directly to the `httpBody` property.

Comment: When I do this    `request.httpBody = jsonData`
 I get an error of `["errorMessage": , "errorCode": 415]`

Comment: That looks like an [HTTP status code](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html). 415 is "Unsupported Media Type". Try setting `application/json` as the `Content-Type` instead of `Accept`.

Comment: Awesome @daltonclaybrook, that was it. Got it sorted now. I'll update the answer here shortly.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the solution firstly we will decode your json file into a data model, then will encode that data model object to the httpBody.

```
let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "zero_RC", ofType: "txt")
let data = try! Data(contentsOf: URL(fileURLWithPath: path), options: .mappedIfSafe)
let jsonDecoder = JSONDecoder()
let json = try! jsonDecoder.decode(JsonObjModel.self, from: data)

//  now encoding that jsonData to the http body
let encoder  = JSONEncoder()
urlRequest.httpBody =  try! encoder.encode(json)
```

The 'JsonObjModel' will be the following

```
// MARK: - JSONObjModel
struct JSONObjModel: Codable {
    let query: String
    let filters: [JSONObjModelFilter]
}

// MARK: - JSONObjModelFilter
struct JSONObjModelFilter: Codable {
    let filters: [FilterFilter]
}

// MARK: - FilterFilter
struct FilterFilter: Codable {
    let field, value, type: String
}
```

Comment: Using this code; at `let json = try!` I am getting this error `(unknown context at $1098d9074).(unknown context at $1098d907c).JSONObjModel`. Any idea why that is? Also, getting the same `["errorMessage": , "errorCode": 415]` when running this code.

Comment: are you sure the json you have provided above is the actual in your file or you missing something?